# sql exception handling

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_createLocaltable
IS
  table_already_exist EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA  EXCEPTION_INIT (table_already_exist, -00955);
BEGIN
  create table local_table as
  select * from supplied_table 
  where rownum < 1;
EXCEPTION
  when table_already_exist then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Table already exists , does not need to recreate it');
END;
```

can anyone see any problem of the above code?

Comment: 6/3            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do DDL in a PL/SQL block like that. You'll need to use execute immediate.

You would need to do it like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_createLocaltable
IS
  table_already_exist EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA  EXCEPTION_INIT (table_already_exist, -00955);
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'create table local_objects as select * from all_objects where 1=0';
EXCEPTION
  when table_already_exist then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Table already exists , does not need to recreate it');
END;
```

Check the [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ#Can_one_call_DDL_statements_from_PL.2FSQL.3F) page on this